# Why is a script from route B is being requested when I am accessing route A?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have this issue when navigating to a route it took a pretty long time to show another. Turns out that in the network tab, I am seeing this huge script that contains content from another router.

So let's say I am trying to access "/badge" route. But in the network, there's this js file that contains content from the "/profile" route which I know shouldn't happen. This script took 10+ seconds to load and it won't let the page be rendered until it's fully loaded. What is going on? I am using NextJS v13 with the pages router (upgraded from v12).

[screenshot of the script in the network tab devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P94e3.png)

As you can see the initiator is `staging.sequence.day/badges`. But checking the script contents it's all content from another router.

What should I do to prevent this from happening? It is causing my app to seem really slow

I checked the actual page for route B and nothing seems off on it. Everything is just plain `tsx` with no data fetching. I am expecting the script for this route to not be requested when navigating to another page.

Comment: Is there a link on route A to route B? Also, are using the new app router?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar nope these two are unrelated. And I am using the old pages router.

Comment: Do you have a Next.js Link on A linking to B? If so, the solution to your issue depends on whether you are using the pages or the app router?

Comment: welp turns out this page is importing a component from that route. and that component also imports so many stuff.